# Azure Data Factory Unzipping many files into partitions based on filename

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have a large zip file that has 900k json files in it. I need to process these with a data flow. I'd like to organize the files into folders using the last two digits in the file name so I can process them in junks of 10k. My question is how to I setup a pipeline to use part of the file name of the files in the zip file (the source) as part of the path in the sink?

current setup: zipfile.zip -> /json/XXXXXX.json

desired setup: zipfile.zip -> /json/XXX/XXXXXX.json

Comment: thanks for the info but that response does not address my issue as far as I can tell. I need the sink to use a different path depending on the name of the json file being extracted from the ZIP. as far as I can tell the decompression step will just extract all files to the same location

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below references can help

> In source transformation, you can read from a container, folder, or
> individual file in Azure Blob storage. Use the Source options tab to
> manage how the files are read.  Using a wildcard pattern will instruct
> the service to loop through each matching folder and file in a single
> source transformation. This is an effective way to process multiple
> files within a single flow.

- [ ] Matches one or more characters in the brackets.
- `/data/sales/**/*.csv` Gets all .csv files under /data/sales

And please go through 1. [Copy and transform data in Azure Blob storage - Azure Data Factory
& Azure Synapse | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage?tabs=data-factory#copy-activity-properties) for other patterns and to check all filtering
possibilities in azure blob storage.

2. [How to UnZip Multiple Files which are stored on Azure Blob Storage
   By using Azure Data Factory - Bing video](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=Azure%20Data%20Factory%20Unzipping%20many%20files%20into%20partitions&docid=608007502126269414&mid=4ADB0CBF7D4CB44C2F344ADB0CBF7D4CB44C2F34&view=detail&FORM=VIRE)

In the [sink transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage?tabs=data-factory#sink-properties), you can write to either a container or a folder in Azure Blob storage.
File name option: Determines how the destination files are named in the destination folder.